# how do I scroll multiple divs with scrollmenu

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make div scroll horizontally with roughly 10 child divs. Problem: nothing happens and text flows outside child div if too long. Tried using scrollmenu from css no luck.

```css
div.scrollmenu {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.scrollmenuchilddiv {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  Width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  Float: left
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollmenuchilddiv">
  Text
</div>

<div class="scrollmenuchilddiv">
  Text is long long long long
</div>
```

Comment: You're aware that you got a typo on your classes? `srollmenuchilddiv` should be `scrollmenuchilddiv`. An advice is to always copy paste CSS class names (and javascript function and variable names) so you avoid this mistake.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I typed it as an error here. It supposed to be scrollmenuchilddiv

Answer (score 1):

I basically just moved `what-space: nowrap` to the child elements instead. I also took the liberty to remove `float: left` because float should only be used to have text float around an element (like images). I instead added `display: flex` to your parent element.

```css
div.scrollmenu {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: auto;
  /* white-space: nowrap; */
    
  /* ADDED */
  display: flex;
}

div.scrollmenuchilddiv {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  /*Float: left*/
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollmenu">
  <div class="scrollmenuchilddiv">
    Text
  </div>

  <div class="scrollmenuchilddiv">
    2. Text is long long long long
  </div>
  
  <div class="scrollmenuchilddiv">
    3. Text is long long long long
  </div>

  <div class="scrollmenuchilddiv">
    4. Text is long long long long
  </div>

  <div class="scrollmenuchilddiv">
    5. Text is long long long long
  </div>

  <div class="scrollmenuchilddiv">
    6. Text is long long long long
  </div>
</div>
```